# Emulator frontend for controllers?

Tags: lubuntu, emulation

I’m working on building a MAME cabinet-type project. This is my first endeavour of this type and I am still relatively new to using Ubuntu.

I have an Zotac MAG HD-ND01 (Intel Atom/2gbRAM/160gbhdd) that I’ve installed Lubuntu 14.04 on. My biggest issue is that I’m looking for an emulator front-end that works well with many emulator types and is great with using a USB controller (PS2/PS3 or generic controller). Researching online doesn’t really provide me with the information that Im looking for without all the comments being 5-8 years old.

I plan on putting this Zotac in my entertainment system where the hope is that I could just turn it on, and grab a controller without needing a mouse/keyboard.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just to note, I ended up using AntiMicro. It can autoload controller profiles, launch in tray, and was stupid easy to set-up and integrate.

```
https://github.com/Ryochan7/antimicro
```

Answer (score 0):

Retroarch is a pretty good choice, it has cores for just about any older emulator type (the newest system I've emulated with it is PS1 with pcsx_rearmed core); as far as control pads, I find that a PS4 pad with ds4drv is the most plug-and-play (of course you have to configure the emulator itself to use the gamepads buttons).

Comment: Well, if this worked for you, please answer yourself and accept it :)